# Access Update with Visual Basic SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Ok, Firstly Hey.

Technically i am new to this site, however i have been using it as a resource for a few years, and it is only because i am stumped that i now come in need of your aid.

I have a VB script that is Querying the Db, filling the intended boxes with the string and displaying it.

My issue is that when i try to use the Update SQL command, it completes however it does not update the DB when i manually check.

```
Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Data.mdb';")
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataTable()
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
da.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("update FDSL set Host=@Host, Owner=@Owner where ID = @ID", con)


    Dim paramID As New OleDbParameter
    paramID.ParameterName() = "@ID"
    paramID.Value() = Label8.Text
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(paramID)
    Dim paramHost As New OleDbParameter
    paramHost.ParameterName() = "@Host"
    paramHost.Value() = TextBox1.Text
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(paramHost)
    Dim paramOwn As New OleDbParameter
    paramOwn.ParameterName() = "@Owner"
    paramOwn.Value() = TextBox4.Text

    da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MessageBox.Show("Record Updated! ", "Update Status", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    Refresh()
    con.Close()
```

I have tried the params using the .tostring on the end as well, but this does not work either.

----------Solved----------------

I must thank @Gord Thompson for this assistance, however i solved the issue by recoding it.

```
        Dim str As String
    str = "update FDSL set Hostname=@Hostname, Owner=@Owner where ID=@id"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(str, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hostname", TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Owner", TextBox2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textbox6.Text)
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
```

This now works correctly thank your for helping again!

Comment: Glad to see that you got it sorted out. I was just about to edit my answer with some simplified code but it looks pretty much the same as yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jet.OLEDB` and `ACE.OLEDB` ignore the *names* of parameters so we need to specify parameters in the exact order in which they appear in the CommandText. In your case you need to change the order in which you execute your `.Parameters.Add()` blocks so you do `@Host`, then`@Owner`, and then `@ID`.

Comment: I have done this so that each .parameters.add() is in sequential order as you have suggested, however it will still not 'save' to the database. I have also changed the query to 'Hostname='" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "'' in an aid to see if direct input would work. 

As you can guess it has not.

Answer (score 0):

I must thank @Gord Thompson for hist assistance, however i solved the issue by recoding it.

```
        Dim str As String
    str = "update FDSL set Hostname=@Hostname, OS=@OS where ServerID=@id"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(str, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hostname", TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OS", TextBox2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textbox6.Text)
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
```

This now works correctly thank your for helping again!