# Updating a remote Access server

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

In the creation of my program, i have found it will be more reliable to supply a local database with the package, rather then connecting to the remote DB for each instance.

Below is my idea on how to do it, however i wish for it to happen automatically for each distinct host that it finds, rather than selecting each member and pressing the button. This is something that i do not know how to achieve.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1    
Dim con as oledbconnection = new oledbconnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='.\localDB.accdb'")
Dim rem as oledbconnection = new oledbconnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='\\server\remote.accdb'")
dim da as new oledbdataadaptor
dim dt as new datatable
dim dt2 as new datatable
Dim Str as string
Dim cmd as new oledbcommand(str, con)

Private Sub Form1_load
con.open()
da.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("select distinct Host from Logs")
da.fill(dt)
con.close

Combobox1.datasource = dt
Combobox1.displaymember = "Host"

End Sub

Private Sub button1_click
con.open()
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from local where host=@host;", con)
cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@host", combobox1.text.tostring)
da.fill(dt2)
con.close()

rem.open()
Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand("update remote set col1=@col1 where ID=@ID;", con)

cmd1.parameters.addwithvalue("@col1", dt2.rows(0).item(1).tostring)
cmd1.parameters.addwithvalue("@ID", dt2.rows(0).item(0).tostring)
rem.close()

End Sub
End Class
```

Any idea's would be appreciated.

*As a note, i realise that JET offers the sync ability however the database is required to be in the 2007-10 format, so ACE is the only option.

Comment: I think you will find that this does in fact work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979758/access-update-with-visual-basic-sql?rq=1 if you want to look here.

Comment: I corrected your code in the way that I would do it. See my update in the answer

Comment: But you didn't read or acknowledge the question. I asked for a way (if any) to automatically update each distinct record that is pulled from logs. All you have done is rewritten my code with more lines in it.

Comment: And not only rewritten your code but correcting some faults such as `oledbdataadaptor`, using `con` instead `rem` when updating remote DB, lack of `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery`..and so on.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `OleDbCommand` does not accept named parameters, so you need to reference them with `?` and pass the parameters in the same order that they appear.

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from local where host = ?", con)
cmd.parameters.Add(combobox1.Text.ToString)
```

Once done, you'll need to fill the `DataSet` with the results of the SQL sentence

```
    Dim DA As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    DA.Fill(DS, "hosts")
```

**UPDATE**

In order to have an equivalent code as yours, I would do something like this

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

Dim con as oledbconnection = new oledbconnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='.\localDB.accdb'")
Dim rem as oledbconnection = new oledbconnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='\\server\remote.accdb'")

dim dt as New DataTable
Dim Str as String
Dim cmd as New OleDbCommand(str, con)


Private Sub Form1_load

con.open()
da.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("select distinct Host from Logs")
da.fill(dt)
con.close


For Each DR as DataRow In DT.Rows

con.open()
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from local where host= ? ", con)
cmd.Parameters.Add(DR.Item(0))
Dim DA As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim DS As New DataSet
da.Fill(DS,"hosts")
con.close()

rem.open()
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("update remote set col1=? where ID=?", rem)

cmd.Parameters.Add(DS.Tables("hosts").Rows(0).Item(1).ToString)
cmd.Parameters.Add(DS.Tables("hosts").Rows(0).Item(0).ToString)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
rem.close()

Next

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I think you will find that this does in fact work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979758/access-update-with-visual-basic-sql?rq=1 if you want to look here. All your asking me to change is how the named parameter is referenced, your also not removing the value that is required.

Comment: Did you read the question before jumping in and *Correcting* my code?

Comment: Did you think about `For Each...Next` instruction?